# Get list of all the collections inside the doc Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking towards listing all the collections under doc of firestore. Is there any way to achieve this?
listCollections ad other stuffs are not working.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, with the Client SDKs to list the sub collections of a Firestore document (nor the root collections of the Firestore database).

On the other hand, this is possible with the Admin SDKs. You may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166) which shows how to use the `listCollections()` method of the Admin Node.js SDK in a Cloud Function in order to get the sub collections of a Firestore document.